# How to keep section header at the top even when we scroll: UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I found this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/) how to make section for collection view. I want to achieve the same effect like in table view when we see section every time on the top even if we scroll table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pick the first library found on google looking what you want: [CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout)

You have a lot of more library available and open source. So, just search a little bit next time, you will find easily your happy ending!

Also, if you don't want to use an external library, you can follow this [tutorial](http://blog.radi.ws/post/32905838158/sticky-headers-for-uicollectionview-using#notes). You will get your goal with it.

Comment: maybe you know here is an issue with jumping header view when it tries to stick the top?